# Retrieve items from a combo box

Tags: c#

Currently I have a comboBox that reads information from outlook, and stores a list as values that can be selected for the comboBox.

I would like to be able to set the text of a button to the values stored in this comboBox.

I have an array of buttons that stores the buttons to be changed. Below is the code, so that on a click, the values from the comboBox will be displayed as the text labels in the buttons, the ?? is where I am stuck.

```
   private void Mmaptsks_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        int count = cmb.Items.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            buttonArray[i].Visible = true;
            buttonArray[i].Text = ??;

        }
    }
```

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
buttonArray[i].Text = cmb.Items[i].ToString();
```

Or if your combo items are not string then you can:

```
buttonArray[i].Text = (cmb.Items[i] as YourType).SomeProperty;
```